# Disable Feign logging on some API calls

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-feign, feign, openfeign

I am using following configuration to enable logging for API calls made using feign

```
#Feign properties
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        loggerLevel: full
```

My application is making calls to 3 APIs and feign is logging request and response JSON correctly for all the 3 APIs . I want to disable this logging for one of the API. Can you please let know on the necessary configuration. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 3 different feign clients for 3 APIs, then you can simply override logging level in this way (assuming that your feign client is called "feignClient2"):

```
#Feign properties
feign:
  client:
    config:
      default:
        loggerLevel: full   
      feignClient2:
        loggerLevel: none
```

But if you have one feign client for 3 endpoints, then the task becomes more complicated. You can inherit [feign logger](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/core/src/main/java/feign/Logger.java) class (or any of its children classes, f.e. [Slf4jLogger](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/master/slf4j/src/main/java/feign/slf4j/Slf4jLogger.java), if you use it now) and override its `logRequest` and `logAndRebufferResponse` methods to not log anything for specific endpoint (you can get the required information from `request` and `response` method parameters respectively). Then add `FeignLoggerFactory` bean with your own logger:

```
@Bean
public FeignLoggerFactory feignLoggerFactory() {
    return new DefaultFeignLoggerFactory(new CustomLogger());
}
```

It will override the default `FeignLoggerFactory` from [FeignClientsConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-openfeign/blob/master/spring-cloud-openfeign-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/openfeign/FeignClientsConfiguration.java#L137).

In summary, I would recommend you to use the first option (with separate feign client). But if you choose the second one, I could help you to do it if you provide the example of your code.